# Xcode quits everytime I click on built & run in VMWare WorkStation 9

Tags: xcode, xcode5.1

When I open Xcode everything works fine, even I can edit the files and do everything and there is no problem in Mac OS X 10.9 itself because all the applications works fine. But when I want to run the application in Xcode. Xcode quits unexpectedly with three options "ignore", "report" & "reopen" what could be the issue?? I have googled and searched many places but no solution :( found.

Issue with Xcode 5.1 and also I tried 5.0.2 but still the same problem.

Comment: you can try virtualBox, but much better will be get native hardware for Mac OS

Comment: I have installed VMWare Workstation and install Maverick and it works flawless with great performance and even virtualBox cannot give that kind of performance that I'm using currently